# Adding custom font to MUI button in React + TypeScript

Tags: css, reactjs, typescript, material-ui, frontend

I am creating my website and I am trying to add fonts to the texts. I tried adding the link of the google font to the head tag of my Index.HTML file as well as adding the font-family to index.css. After this I tried, creating a css class in the style sheet for my website and added the font in the class. Then called the class to the main webpage file in the mui button component. I am unsure why the specific font is not being applied to the text. If anyone can help, it'll be great.

```
<Stack direction='row' spacing={1}>
      <div className='App-logo'>
        <img src={Archit} alt='' height={40} width={40} />


      </div>

      <Button className='button' sx={{ color: 'bisque' }}>=
        HOME
      </Button>

      <Divider className='button' sx={{ color: 'beige' }}>|</Divider>

      <Button sx={{ color: 'bisque', font: 'Neucha' }}>
        About
      </Button>

      <Divider className='button' sx={{ color: 'bisque' }}>|</Divider>

      <Button className='button' sx={{ color: 'bisque' }}>
        Projects
      </Button>

      <Divider className='button' sx={{ color: 'bisque' }}>|</Divider>

      <Button className='button' sx={{ color: 'bisque' }}>
        Activities
      </Button>

      <Divider className='button' sx={{ color: 'bisque' }}>|</Divider>

      <Button className='button' sx={{ color: 'bisque' }}>
        Gallery
      </Button>

      <Divider className='button' sx={{ color: 'bisque' }}>|</Divider>

      <Button className='button' sx={{ color: 'bisque' }}>
        Contact
      </Button>
    </Stack>
```

On applying the classname on the divider mui component, the style is applies but not on the button element.

I have also attached the screen shots of the index.html file and index.css file, and of the stylesheet for my website. Have a look and kindly help if you could.

[App.css](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GWD0x.png)

[index.html](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DHbqL.png)

[index.css](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5u0WT.png)

Comment: When you inspect the `Button` do you see if is overwritten from something else? If you want all your buttons to have the same font then i would suggest to consider it adding in to your theme. Let me know if you are interested in this solution and you  need the code for it. Thanks

Comment: Hey Akis, What you are saying makes sense to me but am unsure of how to implement that. It would be great if you could share the code/method to do so?

Answer (score 1):

One way of using the theme, you can do it like this.

Install your font, in your `package.json` you should see something like `"typeface-montserrat": "^1.1.13",` then create a theme file (replace font 'Monserat' with your font family):

**Theme.jsx**

```
import { createTheme } from '@mui/material/styles';

export const theme = createTheme({
  typography: {
    // fontFamily: ['Montserrat', 'serif'].join(','), Uncomment if you want all the typography to inherit this font.
    button: {
      fontFamily: ['Montserrat', 'serif'].join(','),
      fontSize: 16,
      fontWeight: 400,
    },
  }
});
```

In your App.jsx file:

**App.jsx**

```
import { ThemeProvider } from '@mui/material/styles';
...
const App = () => (
  <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>          
    <Button>Test button</Button>            
  </ThemeProvider>
);
```

With the above all the Buttons will inherit in the selected font-family (don't forget to replace with the font family you want to use). If you want all the typography to inherit this font family then uncomment the line above it with my comments. Let me know if it helps.