# How to insert font face in mui theme

Tags: css, reactjs, material-ui

In index.css file I have a font-face.
I want to avoid this file completely and put this config in a theme.js file crated as part of MUI library implementation. How to do it?

// index.css

```js
@font-face {
  font-family: 'ATTAleckSans_W_Lt';
  src: url('./fonts/ATTAleckSans_W_Lt.woff2');
}
```

// theme.js

```js
const theme = createTheme({
// configure @font-face here.
})
```

[CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/configure-font-face-sofl-h6q39p) Demo

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at a similar answer explaining how you can do it.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/73401472/5376404

After installing the font you can set it in your theme like this (in my example i have set the font to Monserrat)

```
import { createTheme } from '@mui/material/styles';

export const theme = createTheme({
  typography: {
    fontFamily: ['Montserrat', 'serif'].join(','),
    button: {
      fontSize: 16,
      fontWeight: 400,
    },
  }
});
```