# How to override MUI default font roboto to custom font all over the website?

Tags: css, reactjs, material-ui

I'm already overriding globally but still its not overrides in some of the places, still I can see Roboto font especially on MUI select and autocomplete.

```
import { createTheme } from '@material-ui/core/styles';

// A custom theme for this app
const theme = createTheme({
  typography: {
    fontFamily: [
      'DM Sans',
      'sans-serif',
    ].join(','),
  },
  components: {
    MuiCssBaseline: {
      styleOverrides: `
        @font-face {
          font-family: 'DM Sans', sans-serif;
          font-style: normal;
          font-display: swap;
          font-weight: 400;
          src: url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=DM+Sans) format('woff2');
          unicodeRange: U+0000-00FF, U+0131, U+0152-0153, U+02BB-02BC, U+02C6, U+02DA, U+02DC, U+2000-206F, U+2074, U+20AC, U+2122, U+2191, U+2193, U+2212, U+2215, U+FEFF;
        }
      `,
    },
  },
});

export default theme;
```

Answer (score 1):

Please have a look at this post which explains how to set up a font in your MUI theme and also has an example of how you can set it in a component (in case you want for a specific component) as an example.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/73476871/5376404

Also inspect the element that doesn't take the Roboto font to see what is overwriting it.

Hope it helps

Comment: Do I need to override the font family for each component? I mean one place to override all default font to custom font?

Comment: No you don't need, the `<Button>` styling it was only an example IF you wanted to use different fonts for specific elements (also only in case the font was overwritten from something else). Please try to follow the instructions (preferably remove any font styling you did already) and should be easy enough. Let me know if you got stuck

Comment: I'm having issue on select dropdown menu, autocomplete menu still loaded in roboto which is default font. And I found this is a defect raised already by developer in material ui official github https://github.com/mui/material-ui/issues/29703. Not only font none of the styles are overriden on these type of dynamic html content appends to body, let me know if you have any solution for this bro, helps me a lot

Comment: @Karthikkumar the solution with the included example is exactly what I have in one of my projects and is working for the all the components including `Autocomplete`.  The same approach has been used in many projects so I assume there is something wrong you are doing. Please make sure you follow the instructions and follow all the steps. In case you are still stuck create a codesandbox where the issue is reproducible, or provide more info from the inspector, thanks