# Material UI override custom Roboto font

Tags: material-ui

It seems that overriding the CSSBaseline won't work.

I'm building a website using Next.js and the Material UI library, but I can't seem to get the font customization working. I tried to follow the guide and none of it works. I don't know if it has something to do with the CssBaseline theme.

**_app.tsx**

```js
import { createTheme, ThemeProvider } from '@mui/material/styles'
import CssBaseline from '@mui/material/CssBaseline'

const theme = createTheme({
  typography: {
    fontFamily: [
      '"IBM Plex Sans"',
    ].join(','),
  },
  components: {
    MuiCssBaseline: {
      styleOverrides: {
        "@font-face": {
          fontFamily: "IBM Plex Sans",
          src: `url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=IBM+Plex+Sans&display=swap')`
        },
      }
    }
  }
});

export default ({Component, pageProps}:any) => <><CssBaseline /><ThemeProvider theme={theme}><Component {...pageProps} /></ThemeProvider></>
```

**_document.tsx**

```js
// pages/_document.js
import { Html, Head, Main, NextScript } from 'next/document'

export default function Document() {
  return (
    <Html>
        <Head>
            <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" />
            <style>@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=IBM+Plex+Sans&display=swap');</style>

        </Head>
      <body><Main /><NextScript /></body>   
    </Html>
  )
}
```

> SOLVED: Had to put the baseline element inside the theme provider. Duh!

Comment: Please have a look at the link below with this solution for changing the font in your theme and let me know if you find it useful as it also has an example for specifying a different font in case you want it to be different for a specific component. 
https://stackoverflow.com/a/73476871/5376404

Answer (score 0):

SOLVED: Had to put the baseline element inside the theme provider. Duh!